# the differences between function-object and function-pointer?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, function-pointers, function-object

i defined a class, then save the pointer to Foo in the priority_queue, and use the cmp-function that i defined.

but if the cmp-funtion calls the function-object, an error occurs:

```
class Foo
{
    friend bool cmp(Foo *, Foo *);
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int x):val(x) {}
private:
    int val;
};
bool cmp(Foo *a, Foo *b)
{
    return a->val < b->val;
}
int main()
{
    priority_queue<Foo*, vector<Foo*>, decltype(cmp)*> que;
    que.push(new Foo(5));
    que.push(new Foo(6));
    return 0;
}
```

the functione-object runs normally.

```
class Foo
{
    friend struct cmp;
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int x):val(x) {}
private:
    int val;
};
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(Foo *a, Foo *b)
    {
        return a->val < b->val;
    }
};
int main()
{
    priority_queue<Foo*, vector<Foo*>, cmp> que;
    que.push(new Foo(5));
    que.push(new Foo(6));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the IDE is code::blocks

Comment: "an error occurs"?  Really?

Comment: not compile error

Comment: Default-initialized pointer-to-function has the value of `nullptr`. Default-initialized instance of `struct cmp` is a valid instance. `decltype(cmp)` is simply `bool(Foo *a, Foo *b)` - "some function taking two `Foo*` and returning a `bool`". Nothing connects this to a particular function named `cmp`. Similarly, `decltype(42) x;` is equivalent to `int x;` - it doesn't magically give `x` a value of `42`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your `que` variable with the function you wish to use as a comparison.

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    friend bool cmp(Foo*, Foo*);
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int x):val(x) {}
private:
    int val;
};
bool cmp(Foo* a, Foo* b)
{
    return a->val < b->val;
}
int main()
{
    //                                                     vvv
    priority_queue<Foo*, vector<Foo*>, decltype(cmp)*> que(cmp);
    que.push(new Foo(5));
    que.push(new Foo(6));

    return 0;
}
```